# If $\hat{f}(k)=0$ for all $k <0$, then $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$

Tags: fourier-series

I just started learning about the Fourier series, is this statement true or false?

Looking at $\mathcal {R}(-\pi,\pi).$
If $\hat{f}(k)=0$ for all $k <0$, then $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Are you requiring that $f(x)$ is real?

Comment: Does it make a difference? Could you answer it for both maybe?

Comment: If $f$ real, $\hat{f}(k)=\bar{ \hat{f}(-k)}$ so the OP condition implies $f$ real constant though it may be negative (note that the OP condition is unchanged under multiplication by a constant so the original question doesn;t make sense as given, but it should be interepreted as $f$ has constant sign; if $f$ is general, the condition just implies that $f \in H^1$ and there is no reason for either $ \Re f, \Im f$ to be of constant sign

Comment: @Philip730 Unfortunately, since there isn't a well-defined order on the complex numbers, it's not entirely clear what you're asking if $f$ takes complex  values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\widehat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{-iky}f(y)\,dy=\overline{\widehat{f(-k)}}$

So if $f$ is real, your condition implies that $\widehat{f}(k)=0$ for all $k$ and so $f=f(0)=\widehat{f}(0)$ a.s. So, unless $f(0)\geq0$, the answer to your question is general is NO.